# Getting the below error while Publishing the item in Tridion Web 8.5

Tags: web8, web8.5, upgrade, dwt

> JScriptException: Expression 'RenderComponentPresentation()' had error
>   'JScriptException: Expression 'Get("Fields.Exception[0].URL")' had
>   error 'Variable 'Get' has not been declared''
>
> JScriptException: Expression 'Get("Fields.Exception[0].URL")' had
>   error 'Variable 'Get' has not been declared' eval code: Line 1 -
>
> Error: JScriptException: Expression 'Get("Fields.Exception[0].URL")'
>   had error 'Variable 'Get' has not been declared'

The Code written in DWT is

```
var @@arrayname@@ = ["X"<!-- TemplateBeginRepeat name="Exception" -->,'@@Get("Fields.Exception[${TemplateRepeatIndex}].URL")@@'<!-- TemplateEndRepeat -->];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess your template uses the Dreamweaver Get Extension, which is not installed on your system.

See https://appstore.sdl.com/web-content-management/app/dreamweaver-get-extension/669/

Comment: Thank you Rick, the solution helped.. :-)